# Call a link target and a webservice with one click jquery

Tags: jquery, web-services

If my user clicks on a certain link I want to call an Ajax Webservice in the background while the user is transferred to the link target.

```
<script>
    $("a.previewlink").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

prevents the link to work. Fine....

But how can I activate the forwarding to the link after I called my webservice function like e.g.

```
<script>
    $("a.previewlink").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        myFooWebserviceCall();
        nowForwardUser();
    });
</script>
```

At this point "this" contains my url I want the user to be forwarded to.

What should go in the place of nowForwardUser() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could (should) handle the forwarding after the call to the webservice is completed; otherwise it is cancelled. Somewhat like this:

```
    $("a.previewlink").click(function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url, // Url to webservice
            data: data, // Data to be send to webservice
            dataType: "json",
            success: function ()
            {
                // Do something when call is successive
            },
            error: function ()
            {
                // Do something when an error occurs
            },
            complete: function ()
            {
                // Do something when the ajax call completes; eg forward user
                window.location = redirectUrl; // Redirect to redirectUrl
            }
        });
    });
```